# Java Current Date/Time displays 1 hour ahead that original time

Tags: java, date, datetime

When I try to print the current date and time using Calender instance, the result I get is 1 hour ahead from the actual time.

I am working in remote machine which runs with EST time zone. Below is what I tried, but nothing works.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);

System.out.println("Current Date & Time: " +calendar.getTime());

o/p:
Time: Sat Dec 28 11:55:10 UTC 2013

But expected o/p: 
Time: Sat Dec 28 10:55:10 UTC 2013
```

All the 3 types give same result. I couldn't understand what I miss out to get the exact date & time. Is this problem related to daylight time saving ?

Could someone help me to overcome this problem. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is again this old pitfall with java.util.Date: Its toString()-method which you indirectly use when printing `calendar.getTime()` uses your default time zone, not the time zone of your calendar instance (which you set to 'EST').

**Solution:**

```
Date currentTime = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
System.out.println("Current Date & Time: " + sdf.format(currentTime));
```

**Explanations:**

a) In first line no calendar instance is necessary because you are just interested in current global time (the same physical time independent from timezone). `Calendar.getInstance()` is also more consuming resources. Finally, both expressions `new Date()` and `Calendar.getInstance(...).getTime()` have no time zone reference when it is about the internal state. Only the `toString()`-method of j.u.Date uses default time zone.

b) You need to define an output format which is given in line 2. It is up to you to change it. Just study the pattern documentation of `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

c) You also need to define the time zone in your output format to help the format object to translate the global Date-instance into a timezone-aware representation. By the way, I had choosen the identifier 'America/New_York', not 'EST' because latter form can be sometimes ambigous. You should either choose the first form (IANA- or Olson time zone identifier) or the form 'GMT+/-HH:mm'.

d) The output itself is done with `sdf.format(currentTime)`, not just `currentTime` (no implicit call of `toString()`).

e) To answer your question 'Is this problem related to daylight time saving ?': No, the time in time zone EST (America/New_York) is never in DST in december.

**Conclusion:**

If you can, you should try to avoid j.u.Date and j.u.Calendar because there are too many pitfalls. At the moment JodaTime is a better alternative, although not without issues.

Answer (score 0):

### Avoid 3-Letter Time Zone

Never use the 3-letter time zone codes. They are neither standardized nor unique. Your "EST" can mean at least these:

- Eastern Standard Time (USA)
- Eastern Standard Time (Australia)
- Eastern Brazil Standard Time

Use [time zone names](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html).

### Avoid j.u.Date/Calendar

You have discovered one of the many reasons to avoid using java.util.Date & java.util.Calendar classes bundled with Java: A `Date` instance has no time zone information yet its `toString` method confusingly renders a string based on your Java environment's default time zone.

### Use Joda-Time

Use a competent date-time library. In Java that means either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), or in Java 8, the new java.time.* classes (inspired by Joda-Time).

Example code…

```java
// Default time zone
DateTime dateTime_MyDefaultTimeZone = new DateTime();

// Specific time zone. If by "EST" you meant east coast of United States, use a name such as New York.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" );
DateTime dateTime_EastCoastUS = new DateTime( timeZone );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTime_MyDefaultTimeZone: " + dateTime_MyDefaultTimeZone );
System.out.println( "dateTime_EastCoastUS: " + dateTime_EastCoastUS );
System.out.println( "date-time in UTC: " + dateTime_EastCoastUS.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

When run…

```
dateTime_MyDefaultTimeZone: 2013-12-28T18:51:18.485-08:00
dateTime_EastCoastUS: 2013-12-28T21:51:18.522-05:00
date-time in UTC: 2013-12-29T02:51:18.522Z
```

Comment: FYI "EST" is rarely (and incorrectly) used in Australia. I've practically always seen it written "AEST" (I'm Australian btw)