# converting UTC date

Tags: java, date, utc

When trying to convert a utc date I don't get the date in UTC, where is the problem with my code:

```
String date = "Mon, 26 Jan 2015 19:46:51 GMT";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
df.setCalendar(new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date d = df.parse(date);
System.out.println(d);
```

output is as follows:

```
Mon Jan 26 20:46:51 CET 2015
```

I want:

```
Mon, 26 Jan 2015 19:46:51 GMT
```

Comment: What do you mean by "i give no utc date"? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Your input string contains the timezone "GMT" it is the UTC+00:00 timezone and will therefore be used to parse it.

Comment: i dont give the same hour, i give 1 hours plus

Comment: Your input is 19:46 and your output is 19:46 - what do you mean you give an hour plus? where?

Comment: I can't check this for Java right now. But my guess is are using Windows. Windows store local time as system time, most things expect system time be to UTC (guessing Java too, which would then make it return your local time as UTC) EDIT: Also in winter UTC = GMT (for practical human purposes)

Comment: You've given two different versions of the output - why? Which are you actually getting?

Comment: Show us the sample code for both outputs, it is hard to guess what you changed to get the different outputs.

Comment: i get: Mon Jan 26 20:46:51 CET 2015

Comment: If you want to print a date in a different timezone you need to use a formatter with a timezone. IF you only want it in GMT you can use date.toGMTString(). The default is to use your current time zone.

Comment: (can you check if the modified question text is what you want?)

Comment: yes that thank you eckes :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Current Date/Time displays 1 hour ahead that original time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816701/java-current-date-time-displays-1-hour-ahead-that-original-time)

Answer (score 4):

A Date object is just a wrapper around a long variable holding a number of milliseconds. It doesn't keep any information about a timezone or a locale, or any other formatting option.

When you print a Date using Date.toString(), Java uses the **default** timezone (CET in your case), to transform this obscure large number of milliseconds into something a human can understand.

If you want to use a **specific** timezone (GMT in your case) to transform the date into a String, rather than the default one, then you have to create a SimpleDateFormat, set its timezone (to GMT in your case), and use this SimpleDateFormat to transform the Date into a String.

```
String date = "Mon, 26 Jan 2015 19:46:51 GMT";

// this is how you want to parse it
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date d = df.parse(date);

// this is how you want to print it
DateFormat dfo = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
dfo.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(dfo.format(d));
```

Comment: i dont convert my date string, i wont it as date object, but as gmt timezone, not on my local timezone.

Comment: Read my answer again. A Date doesn't have a timezone. It doesn't have one. A Date has no timezone. It's only when you transform it to a String that you use a Timezone. Just like a String doesn't have a font or a color. It's only when you transform a String to pixels on a screen that you choose a font and a color. If you want an object that combines a date, a TimeZone and a Locale, use a GregorianCalendar, or a ZonedDateTime in Java 8.

Comment: No problem. But the OP apparently wants GMT, not UTC.